# Unable to get the exact reason of crash while using Realm + Okhttp

Tags: android, realm, okhttp, realm-migration

I am using Realm and my app crashes with the following traces and I don't get any idea to resolve this. This is the only stack strace that I see on the console. Nothing else :

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: OkHttp Dispatcher
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.Object.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
 at io.realm.RealmConfiguration.equals(RealmConfiguration.java:186)
 at io.realm.RealmCache.validateConfiguration(RealmCache.java:217)
 at io.realm.RealmCache.createRealmOrGetFromCache(RealmCache.java:103)
 at io.realm.Realm.getInstance(Realm.java:213)
 at io.realm.Realm.getInstance(Realm.java:176)
 at testapp.WebClient.WebClientAPICalls$2.onResponse(WebClientAPICalls.java:74)
 at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:133)
 at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

This is the line 74: `Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(context);`

I am not sure what the exact reason is for this crashing. Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Comment: What version of Realm are you using? We just discovered a rather annoying bug in 0.88 that might be the cause of this: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/pull/2419 . A fix has already been merged and should be available soon.

Comment: Hey @ChristianMelchior Thats true, I updated to the version 0.88.0 and it started screwing up. I had to rollback to 0.87.5 and now its fixed. From your comment, I will re-update to the latest version in the next week. Thanks for the update.

Comment: Adding RxJava or a dummy `rx.Observable` file to your project should also solve it: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#jackson-databind

Comment: I just updated to the latest and still get this error

Comment: @Eenvincible I have not checked yet but if you are facing the issue then you can resolve this temporary by reversing the Realm version to 0.87.5 and that's what I did.

Comment: I ended up rolling the version back like you did

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So just for the information to the people out here, as confirmed by @ `Christian Melchior`, it was a bug with the latest version of realm 0.88.0.
Hence I had to rollback to the version 0.87.5 for now in order to resolve the issue.

Christian Melchior, who works at @Realm.io has also confirmed that they are releasing a fix for this bug as soon as possible and hence the latest version should be good to go.

Comment: I upgraded to 0.88.2 and the problem was solved for me. Thanks for the answer Haresh.